# Jupyter lab build fails on fresh Azure Data Science VM (linux)

Tags: azure, jupyter-notebook, azure-virtual-machine

as the title says, i created a new data Science VM (Ubuntu), and running `jupyter build` fails even with just the default jupyter hub extension.

I only installed two other packages before trying this: Azure storage and pyarrow for the reading of Parquet files. Neither of these should have affected jupyter.

The configuration is a Standard B4ms instance, but i tried another configuration and it had the same issue.

The environment is the default py35 conda env. Jupyter is not installed in the root env.
Updating Jupyter or jupyter lab or ipython doesn't help.

Here is the complete output:

```
   (py35) user@VM:~$ jupyter lab build
[LabBuildApp] JupyterLab 0.34.12
[LabBuildApp] Building in /data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab
[LabBuildApp] > node /data/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyterlab/staging/yarn.js install
yarn install v1.9.4
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning css-loader > cssnano > autoprefixer > browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
warning css-loader > cssnano > postcss-merge-rules > browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
warning css-loader > cssnano > postcss-merge-rules > caniuse-api > browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------] 0/822(node:4101) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
info fsevents@1.2.7: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.7" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning "@jupyterlab/vdom-extension > @nteract/transform-vdom@1.1.1" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^15.6.1".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
Done in 30.67s.
[LabBuildApp] > node /data/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyterlab/staging/yarn.js run build
yarn run v1.9.4
$ webpack
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vega' in '/data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/vega-lite/build/src/compile'
    at factory.create (/data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:535:10)
    at factory (/data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:397:22)
    at resolver (/data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:130:21)
    at asyncLib.parallel (/data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:224:22)
    at /data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2825:7
    at /data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:6886:13
    at normalResolver.resolve (/data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:214:25)
    at doResolve (/data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:184:12)
    at hook.callAsync (/data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:238:5)
    at _fn0 (eval at create (/data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at resolver.doResolve (/data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/UnsafeCachePlugin.js:37:5)
    at hook.callAsync (/data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:238:5)
    at _fn0 (eval at create (/data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at hook.callAsync (/data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:238:5)
    at _fn0 (eval at create (/data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:12:1)
    at resolver.doResolve (/data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/DescriptionFilePlugin.js:42:38)
    at hook.callAsync (/data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:238:5)
    at _fn41 (eval at create (/data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:381:1)
    at resolver.doResolve (/data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/ModuleKindPlugin.js:23:37)
    at hook.callAsync (/data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:238:5)
    at _fn0 (eval at create (/data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at hook.callAsync (/data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:238:5)
    at _fn0 (eval at create (/data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at args (/data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/forEachBail.js:30:14)
    at hook.callAsync (/data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:238:5)
    at _fn0 (eval at create (/data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at resolver.doResolve (/data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/UnsafeCachePlugin.js:37:5)
    at hook.callAsync (/data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:238:5)
    at _fn0 (eval at create (/data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at hook.callAsync (/data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:238:5)
resolve 'vega' in '/data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/vega-lite/build/src/compile'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: /data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/vega-lite/build/package.json (relative path: ./src/compile)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    resolve as module
      /data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/vega-lite/build/src/compile/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/vega-lite/build/src/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/vega-lite/build/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /data/anaconda/envs/py35/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /data/anaconda/envs/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /data/anaconda/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /data/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in /data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/vega-lite/node_modules
        using description file: /data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/vega-lite/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
      looking for modules in /data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules
        using description file: /data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          using description file: /data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/vega-lite/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/vega)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          using description file: /data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/vega)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/vega-lite/node_modules/vega doesn't exist
            .wasm
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/vega doesn't exist
            .wasm
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/vega-lite/node_modules/vega.wasm doesn't exist
            .mjs
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/vega.wasm doesn't exist
            .mjs
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/vega-lite/node_modules/vega.mjs doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/vega.mjs doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/vega-lite/node_modules/vega.js doesn't exist
            .json
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/vega.js doesn't exist
            .json
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/vega-lite/node_modules/vega.json doesn't exist
              /data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/vega.json doesn't exist
            as directory
              /data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/vega-lite/node_modules/vega doesn't exist
            as directory
              /data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/vega doesn't exist
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by updating the jupyterhub version from 0.34.9 to 3.5:

```
conda install jupyterlab=0.35 "ipywidgets>=7.2"
```

I followed the explanation using this link: [JupyterLab Support (Python 3.5+)](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py#jupyterlab-support-python-35)

Hope it works!

Comment: It fails.
`Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - azure-storage
  - jupyterlab=0.35
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.`  


Running `conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab=0.35 "ipywidgets>=7.2"`
results in a massive amount of new installs, updates and downgrades (There's a single error at the "Executing transactions" phase, with pyjwt-1.7.1-py_0).  
...
And then `jupyter-lab` build fails with the same error :P

Comment: Yes, there are new installs and downgrades. I just tested it on a brand new Azure Ubuntu ML machine and it worked, did you make any changes to your machine?

Comment: the only things i did before attempting the upgrade was installing azure storage and pyarrow, as i said in the question. otherwise a completely clean VM. Well, since the error message shows a conflict with azure-storage i assume that that's the problem. I guess i'm back to using jupyter notebook. Next time i'll try upgrading jupyter first before i install azure-storage.

Comment: finally tested on fresh fresh VM and it worked. building, installing azure-storage, and then building again works as well! Same with pyarrow.

Comment: ....which broke the conda environment and i had to register the env as a kernel again, but now it works :P

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on the same day as yours.
Is your vega-lite 3.0.0-rc14? If so, try to use 3.0.0-rc13 and build:

First to install rc13 via nam:

```
sudo npm install --prefix /usr/share/jupyter/lab/staging vega-lite@3.0.0-rc13
```

Then change directory and build:

```
cd /usr/share/jupyter/lab/staging
sudo node /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/jupyterlab/staging/yarn.js run build:prod
```

The above solves my problem.

Comment: Thanks, i had to change the dir to `/anaconda/envs/py35/share/<rest of dir>` instead of `usr/share/<rest>`, same for `usr/lib/... `, also python3.4 to python 3.5, and the install seems to have worked, but the build fails:
`$ webpack --config webpack.prod.config.js
/data/anaconda/envs/py35/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:231
                                throw err;
                                ^
Error: Cannot find module '@jupyterlab/hub-extension/package.json'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:603:15)`
...etc...